# How to show that the 3 common definitions/ideas of descriptions of barycentric coordinates are equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Is there some paper or do you know how to show that the 3 typical definitions for barycentric coordinates are equivalent?
[image]
[image]

I only found papers stating these definitions, not proofing their equivalence.
One such paper stating these definitions (p. 1-2) can be found here:
https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/areals.pdf

(It says there is some proof of the equivalence of these 3 definitions left in the appendix, however I cannot find one there...)

Comment: please write all the definitions and avoid referring to links only it will be more convenient for us.

Comment: (3) is the definition of center of mass from (2). (1) is clear if you fix $x+y+z$ and $y/z$ and note that the area changes linearly with $x$ from $0$ to the whole triangle.

Comment: @Eric - I would say that the *definition* of center of mass is the point such that for each line through it, the mass-moments (product of mass times directed distance from the line) sum to $0$., but it is straight-forward to derive the formula from that.

Comment: @Eric Thanks, I managed to to derive (3) from (1) and then (2) from (3) with your help. Isn’t as hard as I first thought :)